# AWS Glue logs to write in Custom Log group

Tags: aws-glue

Need to pass the Glue job logs to Custom Log group (aws-glue/schema) as by default the Glue job logs go into /aws-glue/jobs/output. Found this on aws documentation '--continuous-log-logGroup': 'custom_log_group_name'.
I added this parameter in Glue job as key '--continuous-log-logGroup' and value /aws-glue/schema
and Code as below. But Still was getting Error - GlueArgumentError: the following arguments are required: --continuous-log-logGroup. Can you please let me know any pointers which is missing.

```
`enter code here
`import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,['JOB_NAME','continuous-log-logGroup'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
```

Comment: Can you remove continuous-log-logGroup from your getResolvedOptions and try running your job again?

Comment: Hi Prabhakar,  The continuous-log-logGroup parameter have added in Job parameter in Glue job as key '--continuous-log-logGroup' and value /aws-glue/schema. 
And removed from the Glue code but the logs are writing to both the locations , glue default location /aws-glue/jobs/default and new directory(Log-group) created in Cloudwatch .  Is there any way the logs will write to the new log-group directory ie /aws-glue/schema only??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1984651/pratik-goenka - Can you please help in it.